# No space left on device

Tags: linux, filesystems, centos

I am getting the error "No space left on device" when i tried to scp some files to a centos machine,

tried to check:

```
[root@...]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01 18G   18G     0 100% /
```

And when I do

`du -sh /` -> it gives only 5G

```
[... ~]$ df -i /
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
                     4685824  209516 4476308    5% /
```

seems like file system is full.
How can i find which one is taking these much size?

Comment: Maybe you get more/better answers on 'Superuser' or 'Unix & Linux'. Please show your scp command and the complete df list. Are you sure that you copy to /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01?

Comment: i tried to start some services in that server. it is also giving the same error

Comment: Silly me, my target that was full was a symlink to another drive that was full!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Such difference between the output of `du -sh` and `df -h` may happen if some large file has been deleted, but is still opened by some process. Check with the command `lsof | grep deleted` to see which processes have opened descriptors to deleted files. You can restart the process and the space will be freed.

Comment: I tried to kill those processes and it is working . Thanks!

Comment: How do you restart the process? @user3584460

Comment: @IsraGab If it is a daemon, just stop and start it. If it is not a daemon, just kill with with `kill` or `killall` and then start it.

Comment: How would I use killall to processes that are associated with deleted files?

Comment: @PatricioPiedra First you have to identify the names of the processes (using `lsof` as mentioned in my answer) and then use `killall <PROCESS_NAME>`

Comment: I read about `lsof / | grep deleted` on a page but could not understand what it does. Thank you for your answer here.

Comment: This just causes process to restart. Disk is still in 100% use..

Comment: Nothing happen , no description given after I execute this command

Answer (score 66):

Maybe you are out of inodes.  Try `df -i`

```
                     2591792  136322 2455470    6% /home
/dev/sdb1            1887488 1887488       0  100% /data
```

Disk used 6% but inode table full.

Comment: can we add some more inodes ? :)) (partly joking, partly serious)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem tl;dr no, not really - you can only add more inodes by creating a new filesystem with more inodes and then copying the existing filesystem onto the new filesystem.

Comment: You used 6% of the /home but the /dev/sbd1 used 100% - that is the problem.  Most likely you have way too many log files.  Find large files by running: 

`find / \( -path /proc -prune -a -path /dev -prune \) -o -type f -size +100M -exec ls -s1 {} \;  2>/dev/null| sort -n -r | head -n 20`

Answer (score 15):

To list processes holding deleted files a linux system which has **no** `lsof`, here's my trick:

```
    pushd /proc ; for i in [1-9]* ; do ls -l $i/fd | grep "(deleted)" && (echo -n "used by: " ; ps -p $i | grep -v PID ; echo ) ; done ; popd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the following commands

lsof / |grep deleted

kill the process id's, which free up the disk space.

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: Use `lsof / | grep DEL` on Ubuntu Linux.