# df and du giving different results

Tags: linux, du, linux-disk-free

When I use `df -h` it gives following result for `/appl` directory

```
/appl                   39G    32G   6.7G    83%    /appl
```

But when I enter that directory `cd /appl` and run `du -sh` it is giving me the following result :

```
 4.9G   .
```

If the /appl mountpoint is occupied 32GB why is it showing that it's directories total to 4.9G?

Comment: Are you running it as root? Are you including "hidden" dot files? http://askubuntu.com/questions/356902/why-doesnt-this-show-the-hidden-files-folders

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler No , I am not running as root.Talking about the hidden files how do I include hidden files in my result?

Comment: This looks somewhat convincing: http://superuser.com/a/868800/67909 and run it with `sudo`.

Comment: Show  the output of the `mount` command

Comment: @SantoshA result of `mount|grep appl` is shown below:
`/appl on /appl read/write/setuid/dev=524138f on Fri Jun 28 22:01:34 2013`

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671621/no-space-left-on-device

Comment: What is the result of this command `du -shc .[!.]* *` in the `appl` folder

Comment: @SantoshA It is not supporting the -c option for du

Comment: @user1: Okay : What is the result without that option(`-c`)?

Comment: @SantoshA Kindly find the result below:

`0K   .[!.]*`
 `141M   FDT`
 `215M   FDTCST`
 `634M   FGM`
 `3.0G   FGMCST`
 `196M   HITENDRA`
 `124M   OSD`
 `224K   SUNWj5dmx`
 `1.6M   SUNWj5dvx`
  `22M   SUNWj5rtx`
 `160K   flstr`
` 520M   fmon`
 `163M   jdk1.5.0_16`
  ` 0K   lost+found `

Answer (score 3):

Firstly `df` and `du` are two completely different linux utilities.

`df = Disk free` 
`du = Disk usage`

`df` ([More info on df](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df)) will read the `meta data` of the `disk partition` containing the specified folder which in your case is `app1` and return the `disk partition information` rather than that of the actual directory.

But `du`([More info on du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du)) will runs through the directory tree specified and counts the sum size of all the files under the directory and return the `total space occupied by that directory`.

Next to answer your question: 
`cd /appl` or `cd <mount_point>` is not possible. 
To check where is the partition `app1` mounted use **`mount`** command.

> The confusion you see is because there must be a folder called `app1` under `/` directory and also a partition named `app1`.

Once you locate the `mount point` of the app1 partition, `cd` to that directory and then run `du -sh` the expected output should be `32G` after taking some time.

Note : `app1` partition mount point and `/app1` are not same.

Comment: Excellent coverage on the differences between the two, but how frequently would they differ as significantly as OP is seeing without some other contributing factor?

Comment: @Anthony :Thanks. I have updated my answer now to be more specific to OP's question.

Comment: @SantoshA As I ran the command mount|grep appl I got

`/appl on /appl read/write/setuid/dev=524138f on Fri Jun 28 22:01:34 2013`


Does this not means that the mountpoint and the directory refer to the same thing?

Comment: With this `/appl on /appl ` it does mean that mount point and directory are the same. But I think that is not possible. A folder mounted onto itself which I am not aware? Which OS/System are you using ? Can you give the specific's?.   On a general desktop, a disk/block device is mounted to a folder which appears like this `/dev/sda2 on /home type ext4 (rw)`. But in your case this is totally different

Comment: @SantoshA OS details `uname -a` gives `SunOS efssapp09 5.9 Generic_Virtual sun4u sparc sun4v`

Comment: @user1: One more query, can you share the output of `cat /etc/vfstab` and `mount -p`?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should know the different between `du` and `df`.
Wikipedia says

> `du` is to display the file space allocated to each file

> `df` display the amount of available disk space for file systems on which the invoking user has appropriate read access

So, there are several possible reasons for this to happen

A few examples

1. Some application still **open deleted file**, check through `lsof +aL1`
2. Files larger than their true size. This will fool `du`, but not `df`
3. if there are files at the mount point before something mounts to the mount point, those files will be **hidden** to du, check through `debugfs`