# Brew: No space left

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, homebrew, linuxbrew

I am trying to install phantojs and brew is saying that there is no space left on device:

```
brew  -v  install phantomjs
==> Cloning https://github.com/Vitallium/phantomjs.git
Updating /home/user/.cache/Homebrew/phantomjs--git
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Vitallium/phantomjs.git
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/tags/2.0.1:refs/tags/2.0.1
==> Checking out tag 2.0.1
git checkout -f 2.0.1 --
HEAD is now at 33aaaff... Sync QtBase
git reset --hard 2.0.1
HEAD is now at 33aaaff Sync QtBase
git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule sync
Entering 'src/qt/3rdparty'
Entering 'src/qt/qtbase'
Entering 'src/qt/qtwebkit'
git submodule update --init --recursive
Error: No space left on device - write
```

While:

```
df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        19G   17G  535M  97% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,8G  4,0K  3,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           764M  1,4M  763M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,8G   91M  3,7G   3% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda3       433G   91G  320G  23% /home
```

Does the installation needs more that 500 Mb ?

Edit:
Following the comment, this is the inode information:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        1,2M  376K  819K   32% /
none             955K    13  955K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             951K   518  951K    1% /dev
tmpfs            955K   585  954K    1% /run
none             955K     1  955K    1% /run/lock
none             955K   155  955K    1% /run/shm
none             955K    16  955K    1% /run/user
/dev/sda3         28M  125K   28M    1% /home
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you are [out of inodes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes).  Confirm by running `df -hi`.

Comment: I don't think so (See my update).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No space left on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671621/no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: It's entirely possible that this is a really big thing OP is trying to install...

Comment: If it's cloning and compiling those Qt modules it is. Those are huge

Comment: Hi nos, thanks. Do you want to put your comment as answer ? I can do it otherwise.