# centos rsync No space left on device

Tags: centos7, space

Hint on centos7 when writing to file. No space left on device (28), but I checked the disk and Inodes both have space. I don't know why. Has this ever happened to anyone?

```
[root@GDI2390 sync_backup]# df
Filesystem               1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   52403200   2595000   49808200   5% /
devtmpfs                  32867708         0   32867708   0% /dev
tmpfs                     32874076        24   32874052   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     32874076    279528   32594548   1% /run
tmpfs                     32874076         0   32874076   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   508588     98124     410464  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home 4797426908 902326816 3895100092  19% /home
tmpfs                      6574816         0    6574816   0% /run/user/0


[root@GDI2390 sync_backup]# df -i
Filesystem                  Inodes    IUsed      IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   52428800    89274   52339526    1% /
devtmpfs                   8216927      562    8216365    1% /dev
tmpfs                      8218519        2    8218517    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      8218519      734    8217785    1% /run
tmpfs                      8218519       13    8218506    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   512000      330     511670    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home 4797861888 26409024 4771452864    1% /home
tmpfs                      8218519        1    8218518    1% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 1):

check "Disk space vs Inode usage"

df -h vs df -i

check also - [No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671621/no-space-left-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is ext[3|4], check and see if any of the folders you are rsyncing contains about 1M files. Note it is not a straight forward limit that has over flowed, it is more complicated and related to length of your filenames and depth of b-trees.

It is not disk space or inodes. It is the directory index that may have overflowed. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/644071/ubuntu-12-04-ext4-ext4-dx-add-entry2006-directory-index-full