# Error in tempfile() using template /tmp/parXXXXX.arg

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I wrote a script to aggregate files. Since I have a lot of files in a determined number of folders in a known directory, I wrote the funciton so I can parallelise it. I used it several times with no errors. I just accountered one that I don't understand:

`Error in tempfile() using template /tmp/parXXXXX.arg: Could not create temp file /tmp/parkvVpU.arg: No space left on device at /usr/bin/parallel line 3889.`

The extension `.arg` can change to different ones but the error is always the same. I tried outside of my tmux session (does not work). I searched online bu the closest discussions I can find are [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485743/no-space-left-on-device-when-installing-packages-yet-i-have-space-left) and github errors on different tools. I looked at the `inodes` and this is not the problem.

EDIT: I also compared `du -sh` and `df -h`, they show the same number

The server uses Ubuntu 20.04.4 .

Comment: `No space left on device` could mean you are out of inodes on the file system where `/tmp` resides.

Comment: _"they show the same number"_ - as what? I don't see any number. What is the output from `df -h /tmp` when you get the error you get? If you share the disk with other users and someone else runs something that uses up a lot of space in `/tmp` you may sometimes get these problems

Comment: @TedLyngmo as each others. What I mean is that both commands output the same value of `5.3G`. There are no deleted files opened by a process  ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671621/no-space-left-on-device)) I used `df -h /tmp` and it is used at 76% (49G total, 35G used, 12G free).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I thought that the inodes were global. Apparently not, I was using 100% in /tmp. Learned something and will investigate to understand. You can write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Yama You have a limited number of inodes per partition. They are not like UUIDs. This seems like a nice intro: https://linuxhandbook.com/inode-linux/